# WPF DataBinding with an conditional expression

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am using MVVM pattern and my datacontext of my view is having a property Customer. Now I want to bind IsEnabled property of my textbox based on the value of Customer.CustomerID property. If it is greater than 0 then it should be enable else disable.

I understand I could easily add a bool property in the view model and bind it to the IsEnabled property of my textbox but that seems to be an overkill.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several options.

First,  you can use [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx)

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Customer.CustomerID}" Value="0" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
<TextBox>
```

Be aware, please, that value from DataTrigger's setter can override only the value set in style setter. If you set the value directly then trigger won't work.
The reason is [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

`DataTrigger` works only with equality condition, so if you need to check against the negative numbers aswell, then use second option - [Value Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx)

Comment: Is it somehow possible to make this generic as I am going to use this on several screens, at somepoint its customerID at others it could be employeeID. Something like templateBinding.

Comment: Well, you can try to create style with many different triggers. Then bindig will work only for one of the trigger. Another way is to create  ValueConverter which will accept the whole entity (Customer or Employee) and use appropriate property in the code to return the value for IsEnabled.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the concept of Value converter very well, but want to do the same thing using data triggers as well. What I am able to understand from your comment is I need to create different triggers for different screens and using their property. Am I understanding it correctly? Don't we have some way to do this generic as well.

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly, but I advise you to check it for performance: binding does not like unresolvable paths. I cannot tell you about generic way now. Seems it is not possible. And I offer you to think about testability. You want to put some part of business logic into View. Though this is mostly a presentational logic but I would prefer 'IsEnabled' property in my ViewModel. I can later introduce more complex logic which won't be expressible via DataTriggers.