# WPF Binding - Bind to A when X is checked, else bind to B

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Basically I have a TextBlock which displays the Microphone Gain.

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Calibri Light" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FFF65B60" FontWeight="Bold" Height="35"><Run Text="{Binding AudioRecorder.Gain, StringFormat={}Microphone Gain: {0:#} %}"/></TextBlock>
```

As you can see, this is bound to "AudioRecorder.Gain" however I only want to bind to that value if this checkbox is NOT checked.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Recognizer.AutoGainControl}"
```

if its checked, I want to bind to

"Recognizer.Gain"

Is something like that possible or do I have to merge the two gain variables together?

Comment: You're looking for conditional binding in WPF. Check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542120/wpf-databinding-with-an-conditional-expression) to see how you can implement it.

Comment: Thank you! Hard to google if you don't know the keywords :) This is exactly what I needed. How can I accept your comment as answer?

Comment: You can't accept comment as an answer, I'm not looking for points here, glad I could help!

Comment: Michael is absolutely right, and you certainly *can* do that. However I'd suggest that just because you can do something in WPF doesn't mean that you should. The whole point of MVVM is that the logic is in your (testable) view model and not in the view. In this case you're putting logic into the view and it's not testable. If it were me I'd create a single meaningful piece of data there that expresses what's being represented in the view, whatever that is...what you're seeing in the view must represent *something* of meaning to the user, regardless of state.

Comment: I'm not using MVVM. MVVM is a great pattern but not for my case of use.

Comment: My mistake, I guess I just assumed you were. I'm curious what better UI pattern there is for WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you did succeed or not but some example should remain here for others who might search the same thing:

I have gathered some info and created a version of this :

```
<Window x:Class="ComboItems.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationCore"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="data1" Type="{x:Type system:String}">
        <system:String>Item1</system:String>
        <system:String>Item2</system:String>
        <system:String>Item3</system:String>
    </x:Array>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="visibilityValues" 
                            ObjectType="{x:Type system:Enum}"
                            MethodName="GetValues">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="windows:Visibility" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
      <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton Content="RadioButton1" Name="Radio1" GroupName="radio"  />
        <RadioButton Content="RadioButton2" Name="Radio2"   GroupName="radio"  />
        <ListBox Name="listbox">
            <ListBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource data1}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=Radio1}" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource data1}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=Radio2}" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource visibilityValues}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Style>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

`DataTrigger` will do the job here and according to the `IsChecked` property of both `RadioButton`s it will change the source of the `ListBox`.

Further more, i have used binding to enumerations with the help of `System.Enum` type’s `GetValues` method which accepts a
`Type` parameter so that it knows which enumeration’s values it should return.

The above sample should work without any modification.