# xaml conditional StringFormat

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, binding

I would like to make a `binding` with a "conditional" price format.

More precisely, If another property is at `true`: display price without percentage, if it is at `false`, display price with percentage. Is there a way to handle this case with xaml or should I just make a string price property in my code-behind code?

Comment: I can think of two other solutions - first is a ValueConverter where you pass the condition as a command parameter. The second is using a trigger where you set the [`StringFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) based on the condition. I think it comes down to what you prefer. IMO there are no incorrect ways to solve this (as long as you strive for consistency).

Comment: Talking about MVVM a simple property in corresponding (item?) view model   will do. I often have normal property (e.g. `double Value`) accompanied with one with such logic (`string ValueText`).

Comment: @Sinatr yes I will stay with this solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DataTrigger` like this [WPF DataBinding with an conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542120/wpf-databinding-with-an-conditional-expression). And for other formats of value you can use different `Converters`.

For example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:ToPercentage x:Key="ToPercentage"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AnotherProperty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Price}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AnotherProperty}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Price, Converter={StaticResource ToPercantage}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```