# How to set the ContentPage Title StringFormat through boolean binding and DataTriggers in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have created a "Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)" project in VS 2019:

[image: Project Selection]

and then I chose the "Flyout" option:

[image: Choosing Flyout Option]

I modified two of the auto-generated classes: ItemDetailViewModel.cs and ItemDetailPage.xaml

**ItemDetailViewModel.cs** (Note my change to assign Title as well in the LoadItemId method)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestDefaultAppSize.ViewModels
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(ItemId), nameof(ItemId))]
    public class ItemDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string itemId;
        private string text;
        private string description;
        public string Id { get; set; }

/* MY CODE STARTS HERE */
        public Command ExecuteSwitchTitleCommand { get; }

        public ItemDetailViewModel()
        {
            ExecuteSwitchTitleCommand = new Command(ExecuteSwitchTitle);
        }
        public void ExecuteSwitchTitle()
        {
            SwitchTitle = !SwitchTitle;
        }

        private bool switchTitle = false;
        public bool SwitchTitle
        {
            get => switchTitle;
            set => SetProperty(ref switchTitle, value);
        }

/* MY CODE ENDS HERE */

        public string Text
        {
            get => text;
            set => SetProperty(ref text, value);
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get => description;
            set => SetProperty(ref description, value);
        }

        public string ItemId
        {
            get
            {
                return itemId;
            }
            set
            {
                itemId = value;
                LoadItemId(value);
            }
        }

        public async void LoadItemId(string itemId)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = await DataStore.GetItemAsync(itemId);
                Id = item.Id;
                // ** I Added "Title = " so that the title would be set on load
                Title = Text = item.Text;
                Description = item.Description;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to Load Item");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ItemDetailPage.xaml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="TestDefaultAppSize.Views.ItemDetailPage"
         Title="{Binding Title, StringFormat='{0} SWITCHED'}"> <!-- I bind to "Title" here -->

<!-- And add triggers for the Title to be set depending on "SwitchTitle" -->
     <ContentPage.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentPage" Binding="{Binding SwitchTitle}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</ContentPage.Triggers>

    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
        <!-- and have added a button to toggle the boolean in the view model through a command-->
        <Button Text="{Binding SwitchTitle}" Command="{Binding ExecuteSwitchTitleCommand}"/>
        <Label Text="Text:" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="Description:" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Small"/>
    </StackLayout>
    
</ContentPage>
```

Now when I run this, I navigate to "Browse" from the hamburger menu and click on the first item.
It opens up the ItemDetailPage, with the correct Title; however, when I click the button to toggle the formatting it appears as if the Title ends up empty or doesn't register properly. Here's the kicker, **if I modify the StringFormat in the binding during debugging it starts to work**. I can't for the life of me figure out what is actually going wrong and why this isn't actually formatting the string.

Here is a GIF of the process: [image: Proof of issue]

I've tried restarting visual studio and creating a new project, neither of which worked. I also tried only setting the binding for the Title through DataTriggers (one for SwitchTitle == true, and one for SwitchTitle == false), which also did not work.

If anyone has any suggestions or ideas as to what may be causing this it would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I just tried swapping the condition and it worked. Perhaps this is an issue with the underlying `Page` object and how string formatting is being applied to it? (See GIF)
[image: Somehow it works]

**Additional EDIT:**
Adding `DataTrigger` for each condition also does not work. It is a slightly different behavior that seems to get stuck eventually. See GIF attached:

```html
    <ContentPage.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentPage" Binding="{Binding SwitchTitle}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Title, StringFormat='TEST {0} SWITCHED'}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentPage" Binding="{Binding SwitchTitle}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Title, StringFormat='{0} SWITCHED'}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ContentPage.Triggers>
```

[image: Two DataTriggers ends up getting stuck in a single state]

**Another EDIT:** (to show more of what's going on with the weird behavior)

If I change the `DataTrigger`s to reference a string value instead it is also showing a weird behavior. I have a `DataTrigger` for two different cases, and a default binding otherwise. If I start trying to match the values it eventually fails to revert back to the default binding. There are even cases where the value being checked does not equal the `DataTrigger` value and it still applies the condition. (See attached GIF)
[image: Text evaluations may be off as well]

According to this excerpt from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datatrigger?view=xamarin-forms), if the condition is no longer met, it should revert back to the default value (but it is not in my case):

[image: Microsoft Documentation]

Comment: From my understanding, `SwitchTitle` toggle should trigger the `DataTrigger` on or off, and the default binding to `Title` should be sufficient when the `DataTrigger` is off. I am not trying to change the `Title` property value in the view model, I am trying to apply the string formatting conditionally. Did you happen to see the GIF linked? I believe it shows what I am trying explain.

Comment: "There is no way to "apply the string formatting conditionally"." I believe this is misinformation, I've seen it work with other examples. It even works in the debugger partially, as shown in the GIF attached. Here is another reference regarding datatriggers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datatrigger?view=xamarin-forms

And an additional project example I just found with a quick search: https://bizmonger.wordpress.com/2019/09/26/xamarin-forms-conditional-stringformat/

Comment: Here's an additional resource right on Stackoverflow showing it's possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978537/xaml-conditional-stringformat

Comment: I can not find the cause, but you can try to set the default value of `switchTitle ` as true. You will find it works correctly. In other words, when the title show with the stringformat 
 at the beginning, everything is ok.

Comment: I just discovered that as well, I edited my post to include the screen capture. I'll try that but it still seems weird, almost like it may be a bug with xamarin.forms.

Comment: I also think so, you can report it to the xamarin.forms on the github.

Comment: I've edited the question and title to better represent what you did (adding the missing details which caused me to misunderstand what you meant). NOTE: I agree that its an XF bug; perhaps also try having a string format in BOTH data triggers: in the `False` one, use `Value="{Binding Title, StringFormat='{0}'}"`

Comment: I saw that and rolled it back. You added code that was not part of the original question, and in fact gives it a different behavior. As far as I can tell there were no missing details, since the additional `datatrigger` was not part of the question and since it should work without them. I did keep the `datatrigger` in the title for those who skip over it in the code in question.

Comment: I've added an additional edit to show why just adding the datatrigger to the original question was not correct. It ends up showing a completely different behavior. Theoretically both approaches should work.